# Going from vim 7.3 to 7.2

Tags: vim

I am trying to install commandT plugin and vim 7.3 has no ruby support and i am a newbie to vim. i don't think i know how to complile ruby support myself. If i go back to vim 7.2 will i be missing out on anything that 7.3 has to offer?

Comment: What is your system and where you got vim? I am sure that there is a vim-7.3 with ruby support package somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Once you have installed Vim 7.3 you can find all the details about the changes since Vim 7.2 with:

```
 :help version-7.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Persistent undo is really nice, it would be a shame to live without that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running vim for Windows you could try installing Cream, from here: http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc. That package contains vim 7.3 plus ruby support plus other goodies.

Answer (score 0):

`relativenumber` is working really well for me.